# (most efficient) way to recover part of string by crc32 checkscum?

Tags: php, hash, reverse-engineering, crc, crc32

there is a string $s (e.g. `This is a test string. Just a test string. 123456. abcde`) for which the checkscum crc32 $c (`e18032fa`) is calculated.
now we "lose" 1, 2, 3 or 4 successive bytes of $s.
how can we reconstruct the original string from the damaged string?

my idea was "brute-forcing", so for example if 2 bytes are missing (shown as *):

```
$input = 'This is a t**t string. Just a test string. 123456. abcde';
$input = explode('**', $input);
$part_before = $input[0];
$part_behind = $input[1];
for($i = 0; $i <= 255; $i++){
  for($ii = 0; $ii <= 255; $ii++){
    $word = $part_before.chr($i).chr($ii).$part_behind;
    if(hash('crc32b', $word) === $crc){
      return $word;
    }
  }
}
```

however, especially for four bytes this is very time consuming.

is there a better way? i really think so.

thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: I think there is a better way. I seem to recall that every unique 4-byte value has a unique CRC-32. And according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check#Data_integrity, CRC-32 is an easily reversible and linear function. So if you take the CRC of the first part (to a 4-byte multiple), and the CRC of the second part (starting at a 4-byte multiple), you should be able to compute the missing values and therefore find the missing characters. I don't understand the math enough to say for sure, or how to do it, but it just might be possible.

Answer (score 0):

The code implies that it knows where the missing bytes are located. Is this the intent of this question? If so, one approach would be to restore/replace the missing successive bytes with zeroes and calculate the crc. If the crc is post complemented, it would need to be complemented again to get a non-complemented crc. Then the crc can be cycled backwards to the location of the missing bytes to get the values.

If the forward crc involves a left shift then xor, then reverse cycling involves an xor if lsb == 1, then right shift. If the forward crc involves a right shift then xor, then reverse cycling involves an xor if msb == 1, then left shift.

If the missing bytes location is unknown, there is an issue that at best (depending on the polynomial used), CRC32 single burst correction is usually limited to 15 bits, not quite 2 bytes, and only if the CRC polynomial has enough 1 bits. However, since the single burst is limited to be on a byte boundary, there may be a combination of polynomial and maximum message length that allows for a two byte burst correction. Other than a brute force test involving all combinations of two byte patterns (with an otherwise all zero array) at any byte boundary in a message with some maximum size, I don't know how to prove this would work for a particular case. For X86 with pclmulqdq instruction (most X86 since 2010), there is a very fast assembly based CRC generator using pclmulqdq and the xmm registers.